# What is the purpose of the "do" keyword in Bash for loops?

Tags: bash, shell, for

What is the purpose of the `do` keyword in Bash `for` loop syntax? To me, it feels redundant.

```
for i in `seq 1 2`; do echo "hi"; done
```

Why isn't the syntax like this?

```
for i in `seq 1 2`; echo "hi"; done
```

I'm sure that it *does* fill a purpose. I just want to learn.

Answer (score 126, accepted):

Note that that syntax is inherited from the Bourne shell.

After the variable name, you can have either `in` to have the list of elements explicitly given, or `do`, to loop over the positional parameters.

```
for i in 1 2 3
do
  echo "$i"
done
```

Or

```
set 1 2 3
for i do
  echo "$i"
done
```

Having the `do` in both cases (even if it's not strictly  necessary in the first one) makes for a more consistent syntax. It's also consistent with the `while`/`until` loops where the `do` is necessary.

```
while
  cmd1
  cmd2
do
  cmd3
  cmd4
done
```

You need the `do` to tell where the list of *condition* commands end.

Note that the Bourne shell did not support `for i; do`. That syntax was also not POSIX until the 2016 edition of the standard (`for i do` has always been POSIX; see [the related Austin group bug](http://austingroupbugs.net/bug_view_page.php?bug_id=581)).

`zsh` has a few shorthand forms like:

```
for i in 1 2 3; echo $i
for i (1 2 3) echo $i
for ((i=1;i<=3;i++)) echo $i
```

Or support for more than one variable:

```
for i j (1 a 2 b) echo $i $j
```

(though you can't use `in` or `do` as variable name in place of `j` above).

Even if rarely documented, most Bourne-like shells (Bourne, ksh, bash, zsh, not `ash` nor `yash`) also support:

```
for i in 1 2 3; { echo "$i";}
```

The Bourne shell, `ksh` and `zsh` (but not `bash`) also support:

```
for i { echo "$i"; }
```

While `bash`, `ksh` and `zsh` (but not the Bourne shell) support:

```
for i; { echo "$i"; }
```

All (Bourne, `bash`, `ksh`, `zsh`) support:

```
for i
{ echo "$i";}
```

`ksh93`, `bash`, `zsh` support:

```
for ((i=1;i<=3;i++)) { echo "$i"; }
```

Comment: As always, complete and perfect answer (with a reference to zsh)...

Comment: It's not "strictly necessary" in either case for `for`; the command could be terminated by a newline or semicolon. It makes a bit more sense for `if`/`while` (the former with `then` rather than `do`), but in principle those could have omitted it and required a subshell or braces for the (rare) use of multiple commands. I suspect the real reason that the Bourne shell does it is because ALGOL does it, and we should be glad that `done` isn't spelled `od`.

Comment: @Random832: That's because `od` was already used as the name of the Octal Dump program.

Comment: There is _so much_ here I didn't know. Thank you!

Comment: TIL `for` without the `in` defaults to positional parameters.

Comment: Only “`for i` <newline> `do`” is portable (the one-line form, with or without semicolon, isn’t) in the shorthand, though (“`for i in "$@"; do` is POSIX).

Comment: @mirabilos, `for i do` is Bourne and POSIX, but won't work in some old versions of ash-based shells IIRC. `for i in "$@"` won't work in the Bourne shell if `$IFS` doesn't contain the space character. `for i<newline>do` is indeed the most portable if you need to consider very old BSD systems. See http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/bourne_args/ for details

Comment: That and the GNU autoconf texinfo documentation is where I always look for information regarding shell portability ☺