# What does "test $2 &&" mean in this bash script?

Tags: bash, scripting

I'm looking at a bash script with the following code:

```
#!/bin/sh

set -e # Exit if any command fails

# If multiple args given run this script once for each arg
test $2 && {
  for arg in $@
    do $0 $arg
  done
  exit
}
.
.
.
```

As mentioned in the comment the purpose is to "run the script on each argument if there is more than one" I've some runner code to test this out:

```
# install-unit
# If multiple args given run this script once for each arg
test $2 && {
  echo "\$0: $0"
  echo "\$1: $1"
  echo "\$2: $2"
  echo "test \$2 && is true"
}

test $2 && {
# note this is just a regular bash for loop
# http://goo.gl/ZHpBvT
  for arg in $@
    do $0 $arg
  done
  exit
}

echo "running: $1"
```

which gives the following:

```
sh ❯ ./multiple-run.sh cats and dogs and stuff
$0: ./multiple-run.sh
$1: cats
$2: and
test $2 && is true
running: cats
running: and
running: dogs
running: and
running: stuff
sh ❯ ./multiple-run.sh cats
running: cats
```

I'd like for someone to unpack the `test $2 && {}` part and the `exit` shell built in. In the beginning I was thinking that the `test $2` was checking to see if there are more args, and maybe it is, but it looks weird because it seems like there's two expressions separated by the "and" `&&`, and I'm also just confused what the heck the `exit` builtin does.

Plain english explanations with examples and documentation references are appreciated :)

Thanks!

Edit: Thanks Stéphane Chazelas for that. For anyone who is confused by the change in for loop syntax, check out number 3 in this [geekstuff](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/07/bash-for-loop-examples/) article. To summarize:

```
echo "positional parameters"
for arg do
  echo "$arg"
done

echo "\nin keyword"
for arg in "$@"
  do echo "$arg"
done
```

gives us:

```
❯ ./for-loop-positional.sh cats and dogs          
positional parameters
cats
and
dogs

in keyword
cats
and
dogs
```

Comment: See [What is the purpose of the "do" keyword in Bash for loops?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/306944) about the `for arg do` syntax.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

That's an incorrect way to write:

```
#!/bin/sh -

set -e # Exit if any command fails

# If multiple args given run this script once for each arg
if [ "$#" -gt 1 ]; then
  for arg do
    "$0" "$arg"
  done
  exit
fi
```

I think what the author intended to do was check if the second argument was a non-empty string (which is not the same thing as checking whether there are more than 1 argument, as the second argument could be passed but be the empty string).

```
test somestring
```

A short form of

```
test -n somestring
```

Returns true if `somestring` is not the empty string. (`test ''` returns false, `test anythingelse` returns true (but beware of `test -t` in some shells that checks whether stdout is a terminal instead)).

However, the author forgot the quotes around the variable (on all the variables actually). What that means is that the content of `$2` is subject to the split+glob operator. So if `$2` contains characters of `$IFS` (space, tab and newline by default) or glob characters (`*`, `?`, `[...]`), that won't work properly.

And if `$2` is empty (like when less than 2 arguments are passed or the second argument is empty), `test $2` becomes `test`, not `test ''`. `test` does not receive any argument at all (empty or otherwise).

Thankfully in that case, `test` without arguments returns false. It's slightly better than `test -n $2` which would have returned true instead (as that would become `test -n`, same as `test -n -n`), so that code would appear to work in some cases.

To sum up:

- to test if 2 or more arguments are passed:

  ```
  [ "$#" -gt 1 ]
  ```

  or

  ```
  [ "$#" -ge 2 ]
  ```
- to test if a variable is non-empty:

  ```
  [ -n "$var" ]
  [ "$var" != '' ]
  [ "$var" ]
  ```

  all of which are reliable in POSIX implementations of `[`, but if you have to deal with very old systems, you may have to use

  ```
  [ '' != "$var" ]
  ```

  instead for implementations of `[` that choke on values of `$var` like `=`, `-t`, `(`...
- to test if a variable is defined (that could be used to test if the script is passed a second argument, but using `$#` is a lot easier to read and more idiomatic):

  ```
  [ "${var+defined}" = defined ]
  ```

(or the equivalent with the `test` form. Using the `[` alias for the `test` command is more common-place).

---

Now on the difference between `cmd1 && cmd2` and `if cmd1; then cmd2; fi`.

Both run `cmd2` only if `cmd1` is successful. The difference in that case is that the exit status of the overall command list will be that of the last command that is run in the `&&` case (so a *failure* code if `cmd1` doesn't return true (though that does not trip `set -e` here)) while in the `if` case, that will be that of `cmd2` or 0 (success) if `cmd2` is not run.

So in cases where `cmd1` is to be used as a *condition* (when its failure is not to be regarded as a *problem*), it's generally better to use `if` especially if it's the last thing you do in a script as that will define your script's exit status. It also makes for more legible code.

The `cmd1 && cmd2` form is more commonly used as *conditions* themselves like in:

```
if cmd1 && cmd2; then...
while cmd1 && cmd2; do...
```

That is in contexts where we care for the exit status of both those commands.

Answer (score 5):

`test $2 && some_command` is composed of two commands:

- `test $2` is checking if the string after expansion of the second argument (`$2`) is of non-zero length i.e. it is necessarily checking `test -n $2` (`[ -n $2 ]`). Note that, as you have not used quotes around `$2`, `test` will choke on values with whitespaces. You should use `test "$2"` here.
- `&&` is a short-circuit evaluation operator, which indicates that the command after `&&` will only be run if the command before it is successful i.e. has exit code 0. So in the above example, `some_command` will only be run if `test $2` succeeds i.e. if the string is of non-zero length, then `some_command` will be run.

Comment: `test "$2"` is still not safe if $2 is `-n` or something.  Also, Stéphane's answer is correct that this is just a bad method in the first place.  (e.g. `foo arg1 '' arg3` will fool it into thinking there's only one arg.)

Comment: @PeterCordes, note that both `test "$2"` and `test -n "$2"` are reliable in POSIX-compliant implementations of `test`. Now, for non-compliant `test`s, both will have issues (like some with `test -n` and some with `test -n =` that would return an error). Historically, `test -t` was meant (and documented) to test if stdout is a terminal, so `test "$2"` could not be reliable. POSIX changed that. ksh93's `test -t` still tests for stdout being a terminal (for backward portability) but only when the `test` and `-t` are litteral (not in `test "$2"` or `cmd=test; "$cmd" -t` or `test $empty -t`).