# Bash "for" loop without a "in foo bar..." part

Tags: bash, shell, control-flow

I was recently looking at some code that confused me because it works and I didn't expect it to. The code reduces to this example

```
#!/bin/bash
for var;
do
  echo "$var"
done
```

When run with command line arguments is prints them

```
$ ./test a b c
a
b
c
```

It is this, that is (to me) unexpected. Why does this not result in an error because `var` is undefined ? Is using this considered 'good practice' ?

Answer (score 34):

`for` loops loop on the positional parameters if no `in value1 value2...` part is specified in all Bourne-like shells.

That was already the case in the Bourne shell from the late 70s, though in the Bourne shell, you'd need to omit that `;` (you can also use `for i do` (except in some old ash versions where you need a newline before the `do`)).

See [What is the purpose of the "do" keyword in Bash for loops?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/306940) for more information including more *surprising* variants.

Doing:

```
for i
do
  something with "$i"
done
```

is good practice. It's slightly more portable/reliable than the usually equivalent:

```
for i in "$@"; do
  something with "$i"
done
```

for which the Bourne shell, ksh88 have some issues under some conditions (like when `$#` is 0 in some versions of the Bourne shell (which `${1+"$@"}` instead of `"$@"` can work around) or when `$IFS` doesn't contain the space character in Bourne and ksh88), or when the `nounset` option is enabled and `$#` is 0 in some versions of some shells including `bash` ([again with `${1+"$@"}` as a work-around](https://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/bourne_args/)).

Comment: Had to read this thrice before my brain decided to stop editing out the repeated 'loop' at the start

Answer (score 24):

This is the default behavior, yes. It is documented in the `help` of the `for` keyword:

```
terdon@tpad ~ $ help for
for: for NAME [in WORDS ... ] ; do COMMANDS; done
    Execute commands for each member in a list.

    The `for' loop executes a sequence of commands for each member in a
    list of items.  If `in WORDS ...;' is not present, then `in "$@"' is
    assumed.  For each element in WORDS, NAME is set to that element, and
    the COMMANDS are executed.

    Exit Status:
    Returns the status of the last command executed.
```

So, when you don't give it a list to iterate over, it will default to iterating over `$@`, the array of positional parameters (`a`, `b` and `c` in your example).

And this behavior is [defined by POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html) so yes, it is considered "good practice" as far as that goes.