# Use xargs if IF statements is inside the program code

Tags: bash, password, xargs

There is a program like this:

```
while true
do
    echo 'Your pass: '
    read password
    if [ $password == 'qwerty' ]; then 
        echo 'Nice!'
        break
    fi
done
```

I can use **xargs** only if the program has arguments. But in this case `./program.sh password` doesn't work.
I have a list of password and I need to send them in loop to this program.

`xargs -a list ./program.sh` doesn't work.

Comment: Note that this outputs `Nice!` if the user enters `qwerty`, but also if they enter `" qwerty "` (leading or trailing space or tabs with the default value of `$IFS`) or `q\w\e\r\t\y`... See [Understanding "IFS= read -r line"](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/209123), and also if they enter `-d / -o y` as your forgot to quote `$password`.

Comment: Besides the quoting issue raised by Stéphane (serious hole, btw, as it doesn't really matter what the password is), it would also be better if you do `stty -echo` before the `read` and `stty echo` after it, so the password is not displayed in the terminal.

Answer (score 11):

There's no reason to use `xargs` here, you can simply do:

```
while IFS= read -r password
do
    if [ "$password" = 'qwerty' ]; then 
        echo 'Nice!'
        break
    fi
done
```

And then run it as:

```
./program.sh < list
```

If you really want `xargs`, you can do something like:

```
for password do
  case "$password" in
    'qwerty')
      echo 'Nice!'
      ;;
  esac
done
```

And then:

```
xargs -rd '\n' -a list ./program.sh
```

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas thanks for the edit, I should have done most of those myself. Why change the `"$@"` though? Is `$@` not portable? And why have them on the same line and without a `;` before `do`?

Comment: `for i do` is the Bourne/POSIX<2016 syntax. `for i\ndo` is the most portable if you ever come across ancient  BSDs. `for i; do` is now also standard with the 2016 edition of the standard. `for i in "$@"` has a number of issues with a number of shells in corner cases. It's discussed in some Q&A here I beleive.

Comment: Note that neither `-a`, `-r` nor `-d` are standard `xargs` options.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I'm having trouble finding that Q&A on the issues of `for i in "$@"; do` vs `for i; do`. It sounds very interesting, as I thought they'd have an identical effect. Would you do the favour of linking it for all of us?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Nevermind. I think I found it [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/417292/bash-for-loop-without-a-in-foo-bar-part/417296#417296).