# Is for(( ... )){ ... ;} a valid shell syntax? In which shells?

Tags: bash, shell, zsh, ksh

The expresion:

```
$ ksh -c 'for ((i=0;i<10;i++)){ echo $i;}'
0
1
2
3
4
```

works correctly.

I fail to find the description of this syntax in which the `{...;}` is replacing the `; do ...; done` in the manual.

Is there a reference in the manual?
For which shells do that work correctly?

Comment: Related: [What is the purpose of the "do" keyword in Bash for loops?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/306940)

Answer (score 29):

`{ ...; }` was already accepted in place of `do ...; done` in `for` loops in the first version of the Bourne shell in Unix V7 in the late 70s (see [the source code](https://github.com/dspinellis/unix-history-repo/blob/Research-V7/usr/src/cmd/sh/cmd.c#L240)) though never documented as far as I know.

All of `ksh` (both the original one derived from the Bourne shell, and the ksh93 rewrite), `pdksh`¹ (and derivatives), `bash` (from the start in 1989) and `zsh` support it. I don't know of any `ash` derivative that does. `yash` doesn't either but `yash` was written to the POSIX standard.

In `zsh`, support was added with 2.0 in 1991, but as part of a new range of short forms for most constructs which goes beyond the Bourne syntax. It's not only `for i in 1 2; { ...; }`, it's `for i in 1 2; any-command` (and variants thereof). And it is documented [there](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Shell-Grammar.html#Complex-Commands) and [has been since its introduction](https://groups.google.com/forum/message/raw?msg=comp.sources.misc/NnkewmK-26s/dXy0FqhBBkwJ).

AFAIK, beside `zsh`, only pdksh documents it (for both `for` and `select`).

As for the `((init; condition; action))` form, that comes from `ksh93` and was copied by `zsh` and `bash`.

Neither that `((...))` nor the `{ ...; }` in place of `do ...; done` are POSIX.

See also [What is the purpose of the "do" keyword in Bash for loops?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/306940) for more `for` loop forms.

---

<sup>¹ not earlier versions, nor the Forsyth shell on which it is based. It was added in 5.1.1 in 1994 and that probably explains why it became documented there</sup>

Comment: Wow, Mr Bourne *fully* embraced the use of the c preprocessor in that 70s source code.